# Parsing advanced XML in java

Tags: java, xml

Hi I want to parse pretty strange xml looking like this:

```
<foo>
    <foo1>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
    </foo1>
</foo>

<foo>
    <foo1>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
        <foo2></foo2>
    </foo1>
</foo>
```

I cant get values from foo2 when I used this tutorial:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html

But it don't work if we have same parameters like `foo2`

Comment: you should google for `Jaxb`, or click [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) tutorial, remember, don't try to invent wheel

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Comment: You should maybe tell us to what you are going to parse this.  To a `list`?  To a `String`? To a `String[]`? To your own Data Structure?

Comment: This is not valid XML.  Open in any standard web browser to be told why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Normalize your XML then create a `Document` by that XML then follow the below code

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("foo");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) { // loop for foo
            Node nodeTable = nList.item(temp);
            Element xmlFoo = (Element) nodeTable;
            if (nodeTable.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            NodeList nodeListFoo1 = xmlFoo.getElementsByTagName("foo1");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListFoo1.getLength(); i++) { // loop for foo1
                Node nodefoo2 = nodeListFoo1.item(i);
                Element elementfoo1 = (Element) nodefoo2;
                // Collect foo2 
                NodeList nodeListfoo2Name = elementfoo1.getElementsByTagName("foo2");
                for (int j = 0; j < nodeListfoo2Name.getLength(); j++) { //// loop for foo2
                    Node nodefoo2Name = nodeListfoo2Name.item(j);
                    Element elementfoo2Name = (Element) nodefoo2Name;
                    //TODO: write code here, what you want to collect from foo2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you must have a parent item to hold all the other elements, like the example below:

```
<parentFoo>
    <foo>
        <foo1>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
        </foo1>
    </foo>

    <foo>
        <foo1>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
           <foo2></foo2>
        </foo1>
    </foo>
</parentFoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use [`jdom2`](http://www.jdom.org/). It's an free library and should do the job without troubles.

At first you parse the XML string into an `Document`. This document represent your compleat xml then.

```
    SAXBuilder reader = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = reader.build(new File("Path to XML")); //also string is possible
    }
    catch (JDOMException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After this you can iterate over every Childs of it. That would be the outer one. If you dont know how much childdepth there are you can always check if `childCount != 0` than there is one more. Maybe create a recursive method for that.

```
for (Element e : doc.getRootElement().getChildren())
    {
         // do something with the childs here for example
         e.getText(); //would be "" in your case
         for(Element child : e.getChildren()){
             //do something with the child child
         }
    }
```

And so on. You can get every `attribute` or `getName()` or such from the Elements.

[Here is one more Tutorial for the DOM parser.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score -1):

I agree that JAXB is the way to go. Use an online XSD generator for you xml. Take that XSD and use the JAX-B  binding that Netbeans provides to create the Java classes.

You can then use standard JAX-B API to marshall and unmarshall.

Comment: Why a -1? This is a perfectly legitimate answer?