# Parsing XML file list elements with Simple XML in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, jaxb, simple-framework

I need to parse a large xml file with SImple XML, (I really want to use Simple XML). I created objects with XSD, converted them from JAXB specific to SimpleXML specific adnotated objects.

The XML looks like this:

```
    <House>
      <MainLevel Name="~#editRoom" IsHidden="false">
        <ChildLevel Name="Television" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="Chair" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="Table">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="ChamberName" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
          <ChildLevel Name="ChamberName" Category="Bathroom">
          <string>BathTub</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="Door", Category="DiningRoom">
          <boolean>isOpen</boolean>
        </ChildLevel>
     </MainLevel>
    <MainLevel Name="~#editRoom" IsHidden="false">
        <ChildLevel Name="Television" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="Chair" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="Table" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="ChamberName" Category="Livingroom">
          <string>TestRoom</string>
        </ChildLevel>
          <ChildLevel Name="ChamberName" Category="Bathroom">
          <string>BathTub</string>
        </ChildLevel>
         <ChildLevel Name="Door">
          <boolean>isOpen</boolean>
        </ChildLevel>
     </MainLevel>
</House>
```

What are your suggestions. Please help.Thx.

Comment: Possible same question [xml-parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917165/parsing-advanced-xml-in-java/21917599#21917599)

Comment: No, the linked question is about the java xml api, this is about the simple framework (xml de-/serialization (java)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best write 3 classes:

1. A **`House` class**, (= the root) containing a (inline-) list of `MainLevel`
2. A **`MainLevel` class**, containing a (inline-) list of all `ChildLevel`
3. A **`ChildLevel` class**, containing the value

Here's some ***pseudocode***:

```
@Root(...)
public class House
{
    @ElementList(inline = true, ...)
    private List<MainLevel> levels;

    // ...
}

public class MainLevel
{
    @Attribute(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Attribute(name = "IsHidden")
    private bool hidden;
    @ElementList(inline = true, ...)
    private List<ChildLevel> childLevels;

    // ...
}

public class ChildLevel
{
    @Attribute(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Attribute(name = "Category", required = false)
    private String category;

    // ...
}
```

Since a `ChildLevel` can have different types, you have to take care about this. Either implement all types and mark them as not required, or make subclasses.

Comment: OK. So If I happen to have elements ore attributes that pop up only in some places along the node structure, I will have to annotate as not required and it should work. But what if I have another element nested in only one of the child levels nodes, and the nested node has an inline node list.Would the same rules apply.I'll post tomorrow the exact structure to clarify.Thanks for your input really appreciate it.

Comment: @ollo - can u plz help me wid my issue. Which is- i want to make a xml file where i can put some values against some integer numbers. i.e- each int number will contain a value. Plus, ill be taking the values from editText box. so, when a number & a value will be entered -it will be appended in the xml file with the previous data. Again, i need to find a value from that xml file against a given int(User input). How to do it? m i going to use map? idk how to solve it.. help me..

Comment: Please post a new Question, it's hard to solve questions through comments only.