# Xml Parsing in Android : issue with XML structure

Tags: java, android, parsing, xml-parsing

I searched over for dummies and was successful in parsing and xml file with one main Node and multiple inner node like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<RECORDS>
    <values>
        <id1>..</id1>
        <id2>..</id2>
    </values>
    <values>
        <id1>..</id1>
        <id2>..</id2>
    </values>
</RECORDS>
```

using this code snippet:

```
doc = xmlParser.getDomElement(XML_DATA_STRING);
nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("values);
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    xmlParser.getValue(e,"id1");
.
.
.
}
```

But now there is a small change in my XML file;
There will be anther subParent for each `<values>` element;

the data will be in this format

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<RECORDS>
  <SubParent1>
    <values>
        <id1>..</id1>
        <id2>..</id2>
    </values>
    <values>
        <id1>..</id1>
        <id2>..</id2>
    </values>
  </SubParent1>
  <SubParent2>
    <values>
        <id1>..</id1>
        <id2>..</id2>
    </values>
    <values>
        <id1>..</id1>
        <id2>..</id2>
    </values>
  </SubParent2>
</RECORDS>
```

Please help me I dont know anything about the XML parsing;
Thank you.

Comment: Well then learn about XML parsing? Google *XML Sax Parser*

Comment: take a look [almost same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917165/parsing-advanced-xml-in-java/21917599#21917599)