# how to get all roots of a child in xml using java

Tags: java

i have a xml file like below.

```
<root>
 <subchildA>
    <childA>
         <dataA>data</dataA>
         <dataB>data</dataB>
    </childA>
 </subchildA>
 <subchildB>
    <childB>
         <dataA>data</dataA>
         <dataB>data</dataB>
    </childB>
 </subchildB>
</root>
```

i can get the node values eg(dataA or dataB 's value). But i need to get all the roots of data nodes.

eg dataA is in childA->subchildA->root. i am using java `DocumentBuilder` for  reading.

EDIT

using the below code i can recursively read nth child but i cant get all roots.

```
public static void readNode( Node node) {
        String id;
        NodeList subList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; null != subList && j < subList.getLength(); j++) {
            Node tmpNode = subList.item(j);
            if (tmpNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                Element element = (Element) tmpNode;
                id = element.getAttribute("id");

                    System.out.println( id + ":"
                            + tmpNode.getTextContent());

                readNode( tmpNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: All? There can only be one root.

Comment: Can you post your attempt(code)?

Comment: hope you will find your [solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917165/parsing-advanced-xml-in-java/21917599#21917599)

Comment: @Suzon the solution is fine but there fixed no of sub child but in my case i dont know how many inner child will come. eg childA can contain  another inner child. thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to traverse xml backwards to reach root node.

Using `Node Node.getParentNode()` method you can get parent node of the current node and apply same on parent node until you reach required node(Parent).

Comment: Node.getParentNode() is taking me to subchildA but i want subchildA-childA for dataA

Comment: This is how getParentNode() works.

`node(childA) = node(dataA).getParentNode();
node(subchildA) = node(childA).getParentNode();`

_I've put node names in brackets for better understanding._

Comment: using reverse traversing the above code helped me to obtain the result thanks Mr.BwithLove

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB, Java architecture for xml binding, to marshalling and unmarshalling xml documents to java beans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getParentNode to find the Parent node of and particular node.

Answer (score 0):

`subChild` or `child` will not be a problem, Below example will work for:

```
 <root>
     <xyz>
        <childxyz>
             <dataxyz>
             .......
             .......
     .......
     .......
     <pqr>
        <childpqr>
             <datapqr>
             .......
             .......
```

And so on...

Try like this:

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList noteListRoot = root.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < noteListRoot.getLength(); i++) {
    Node subChild = noteListRoot.item(i);
    if (subChild.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        NodeList subChildNList = subChild.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < subChildNList.getLength(); j++) {
            Node childNode = subChildNList.item(j);
            if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NodeList childNodeList = childNode.getChildNodes();
                for(int k=0; k<childNodeList.getLength(); k++){
                    Node dataNode = childNodeList.item(k);
                    if (dataNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        System.out.println(dataNode.getNodeName() +" ->  "+dataNode.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will work only if you have only 4 levels if n levels inside a root the above code fails